# Capistrano deployment "the task staging does not exists"

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano, web-deployment

I was hoping someone could help me, I am going in to first experiences of deploying sites via capistrano however, whenever I run `cap deploy:check` I get the error **the task `staging' does not exist**, what is the problem?

This is is my deploy.rb

```
set :application, "Myproject"
set :repository, "******@bitbucket.org/simonainley/myproject.git"

set :scm, :git
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent =>true}

set :stages, %w(staging production)
set :default_stage, "staging"
require 'capistrano/ext/miltistage'
```

And this is my staging.rb

```
role :server, "**.**.**.***"
set :user, "user"
set :password, "password"

set :branch, "dev"
set :web_directory, "/home/***/public_html/staging/****"

namespace :deploy do |
    desc "Deploys code to the staging enviroment."
    task :default_stage, :roles => :server, :except => {:;no_release => true}
        run [
            "cd #{web_directory}",
            "git reset --hard",
            "git checkout #{branch}",
            "git fetch",
            "git pull origin #{branch}" ].join("; ")
    end
end
```

I assume I am missing a setting or variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a typo; the line should be:

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
```